# C++ SIGSEGV error

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

The code is giving SIGSEGV error. How can I remove it? The code is multiplying elements of an array and modulo 10<sup>9</sup>+7 at each step of multiplication.

```
int main()
{
  int n;
  int A[10];
  cin >> n;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    cin >> A[i];
  int ans = 1;
  int m   = 1000000007;
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    ans = (ans * A[i]) % m;
  }
  cout << ans;
}
```

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What do you do to make sure `A[i]` doesn't read outside of `A`?

Comment: Is `n` less than or equal to 10?

Answer (score 0):

In your code the array A is declared as of 10 elements. However, afterwards the amount of elements to handle is asked to user. Also, potentially the first number enterred by the user seems to be either negative or more than 10. In this case you need to test the enterred value.

Besides that, you can use std::vector instead of the array A to be of a dynamic size. Then after the user has given the amount of elements (with the first std::cin) you can set the size of the vector. The rest code then will remain nearly the same with some cosmetical changes.

Comment: counter offer: Ditch the array entirely. Replace it with nothing. Process the numbers as they come in.

Comment: I may assume this is a kind of a home task to learn how the arrays work :)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C++ do not magically resize themselves.   As a result, if the user enters a value for `n` of `10` or more, both loops attempt to access elements of the array `A` past its end.   For example, if `n` is `13`, the loops will access `13` elements of a `10` element array named `A`.

That is undefined behaviour.   If your host system is some unix variant (e.g. linux) and the operating system detects your program accessing memory it shouldn't, it will send a `SIGSEGV` signal to your program, which forceably causes the program to exit.    However, that is only one possible symptom of many.

Given that this is a homework exercise, I'll just say you need to work out a way to dynamically allocate an array with `n` elements - AFTER reading `n`.   Using a standard container (like `std::vector<int>`) is one way - but, depending on what your homework requires, may not be permitted.   In that case, look up operators `new` and `delete`.   (No, I will not be more specific - this is your homework, not mine)